# Does any OS/app support Roman numerals in natural numeric sort?

Tags: sorting, operating-systems

In modern operating systems, a list of files named 1.jpg through 10.jpg is sorted with 10.jpg appearing after 9.jpg, as it should. But I don't know of any natural sort implementation that accounts for Roman numerals.

This is a disaster for classical music tracks:

[image]

Has anyone seen a Roman numeral natural sort in the wild? Is there a precedent of support for this in any application?

Comment: Those look like letters (I, II, III, ...), not like roman numerals (Ⅰ, Ⅱ, Ⅲ).

Answer (score 0):

Well, C `qsort` (for one) supports it because you provide your own comparison function. Your comparison function can be arbitrarily complex.

But that's only if this is a programming question (you asked about libraries). If it's a file manager question for an OS, it probably *does* belong on SuperUser (let us know if this is the case and we'll nudge it over there).

Comment: It's more of a "has anyone seen this in the wild" so I suppose it's better off at SuperUser.